# Redefine align* to do the same thing as align, for use with autonum package

Tags: amsmath, autonum

I'm writing a large thesis, and recently discovered the `autonum` package, which will automatically *only* number equations which are referenced in the text. This seems like a very good addition to my preamble, but unfortunately including `autonum` will undefine all the starred `amsmath` environments (mostly affects `align*` in my case), and so a document which uses any of the starred environments won't compile.

Now I'm not 100% certain that I want to commit to using the `autonum` package just yet, so instead of replacing all instances of `align*` with `align` (which is hard to undo down the road), I wanted to simply redefine `align*` environment to do the same thing as `align` does.

My attempts so far have been

```
\newenvironment{align*}
{\begin{align}}{\end{align}}
```

which fails with the error `Command \align* already defined`. So I tried `\renew...`

```
\renewenvironment{align*}
{\begin{align}}{\end{align}}
```

but that fails with the error `Environment align* undefined`.

#### Minimal working (or non-working if you want) example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

% this gives the errors
%   Command \align* already defined. {\begin{align}}{\end{align}}
%   Environment align* undefined. \begin{align*}
% \newenvironment{align*}
% {\begin{align}}{\end{align}}

% this gives the error
%   Environment align* undefined. \begin{align*}
% \renewenvironment{align*}
% {\begin{align}}{\end{align}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align} % labelled and referenced equation -- will get numbered
    a = b + c
    \label{eq:eq1}
\end{align}
Refer to equation \cref{eq:eq1}.
\begin{align} % labelled equation -- will not get numbered
    a = b + c
    \label{eq:eq2}
\end{align}
\begin{align*} % starred envir, will crash compilation
    a = b + c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that the `autonum` package should have an option for not disabling the starred environments. This could be a feature request to the author.

Comment: \renewenvironment{align*}{\align\color{red}}{\endalign}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do all starred environments by doing the appropriate definitions at begin document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\restore@Environment}[1]{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \csletcs{#1*}{#1}%
    \csletcs{end#1*}{end#1}%
  }%
}
\forcsvlist\restore@Environment{alignat,equation,gather,multline,flalign,align}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align} % labelled and referenced equation -- will get numbered
    a = b + c
    \label{eq:eq1}
\end{align}
Refer to equation \cref{eq:eq1}.
\begin{align} % labelled equation -- will not get numbered
    a = b + c
    \label{eq:eq2}
\end{align}
\begin{align*}
    a = b + c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In my experiment, using `\tag` will add the tag independently of whether the tagged equation is referenced.

[image]

Comment: @Patrick Häcker Do you think it would be possible to implement that into your package?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if I understand correctly what you are asking for, but see if this works for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

% this gives the errors
%   Command \align* already defined. {\begin{align}}{\end{align}}
%   Environment align* undefined. \begin{align*}
% \newenvironment{align*}
% {\begin{align}}{\end{align}}

% this gives the error
%   Environment align* undefined. \begin{align*}
% \renewenvironment{align*}
% {\begin{align}}{\end{align}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\@namedef{align*}{%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredfalse\m@ne
}
\@namedef{endalign*}{\endalign}

\makeatother

Some text.
\begin{align} % labelled and referenced equation -- will get numbered
    a = b + c
    \label{eq:eq1}
\end{align}
Some text.  Refer to equation \cref{eq:eq1}.
\begin{align} % labelled equation -- will not get numbered
    a = b + c
    \label{eq:eq2}
\end{align}
Some text.
\begin{align*} % starred envir, will crash compilation
    a = b + c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Note that the patch to the commands must be inserted *after* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: A very good solution, but I prefer [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s solution. Also, he was first :)

Comment: @FilipS.: I think I answered first, but I too prefer egreg’s solution over mine: it is more elegant.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I must have misread the timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are free to use LuaLaTeX, adding the following seven lines of code to your preamble will automatically replace all instances of `{align*}` with `{align}` "on the fly", *before* TeX's "eyes" start their processing. This way, LaTeX will never "see" `align*` environments, as all of them will have been converted to `align` environments.

```
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function alignstar ( buff )
   return ( string.gsub ( buff, "{align%*}", "{align}" ) )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", alignstar, "alignstar" )
\end{luacode}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref,autonum}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function alignstar ( buff )
   return ( string.gsub ( buff, "{align%*}", "{align}" ) )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", alignstar, "alignstar" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\begin{align} % labelled and referenced equation -- will get numbered
    a = b + c
    \label{eq:eq1}
\end{align}
Refer to equation \cref{eq:eq1}.
\begin{align} % labelled equation -- will not get numbered
    a = b + c
    \label{eq:eq2}
\end{align}
\begin{align*} % starred envir, will no longer crash compilation
    a = b + c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you need to fix not only all `align*` environments but all `gather*` environments as well, all you'd need to do is replace the line

```
   return ( string.gsub ( buff, "{align%*}", "{align}" ) )
```

with

```
   buff = string.gsub ( buff, "{align%*}", "{align}" ) 
   buff = string.gsub ( buff, "{gather%*}", "{gather}" ) 
   return buff
```

Comment: A very slick solution, and how I envisioned solving it, but I think I prefer pdfLaTeX for now.

Comment: @FilipS. - Glad you liked my solution. :-) Just out of idle curiosity: Is there something about LuaLaTeX that's giving you pause or is otherwise deterring you from using it?

Comment: Mostly just that 1) I don't know Lua 2) it seems kind of overkill for this problem considering egreg's nice LaTeX-solution, and 3) I would have to reconfigure my build setup (I'm using Sublime Text 3 + LaTeXing on Windows 10 to compile).